# How to clear gridview data in winforms devexpress?

Tags: winforms, gridview, devexpress

In my gridview i have data's and after calculation I need to clear the gridview ? how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not clear the GridView in common case. Just clear the data source that the GridView is bound to.
Or use the [ColumnView.DeleteRow](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_DeleteRowtopic) method to delete the specific row.
Hint: If the code that performs a sequence of adding/deleting/modifying operations is wrapped with the [BeginDataUpdate](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_BeginDataUpdatetopic) and [EndDataUpdate](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_EndDataUpdatetopic) methods, the View will perform only a single data update reflecting all made changes after the EndDataUpdate method is called.

Please refer the [Adding and Deleting Records](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument752) help-article for more details.

Comment: HI, I don't want to clear the data source because i want to use that gridview after clearing. I want to delete all row's from gridview. How to do this ?

Comment: In common case, when you make some changes in underlying data source (e.g. removing all records) the grid view will reflect these changes accordingly. Anyway you can use the methods mentioned in my answer